# Retry async aiohttp requests for certain status codes

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

What is the best way to retry async API calls using aiohttp? I want to retry the request for the standard socket error, timeout error, etc as well as for certain status codes `500, 501`. I have tried using [aiohttp_async](https://github.com/inyutin/aiohttp_retry), but can't get it to work:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from aiohttp_retry import RetryClient

# Async single retry fetch
async def async_retry_fetch(url, retry_client):
    async with retry_client.get(url, retry_attempts=3, retry_for_status=[500, 501]) as response:
        try:
            data = await response.json()
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception("Could not convert json")
    return data

async def main():
    urls = [
        "https://httpstat.us/200",
        "https://httpstat.us/500"
    ]
    api_calls = []
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        retry_client = RetryClient(session)
        for url in urls:
            api_calls.append(async_retry_fetch(url, retry_client))
    res = await asyncio.gather(*api_calls, return_exceptions=True)
    print("RESULT", res)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
RESULT [AttributeError("'ClientSession' object has no attribute 'debug'"), AttributeError("'ClientSession' object has no attribute 'debug'")]
```

Comment: it looks like you have `aiohttp_retry` [version 2.x](https://github.com/inyutin/aiohttp_retry) but you use arguments for [version 1.2](https://github.com/inyutin/aiohttp_retry/tree/v1.2) and this generate `AttributeError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have installed `aiohttp_retry` [version 2.x](https://github.com/inyutin/aiohttp_retry)
but you use arguments for [version 1.2](https://github.com/inyutin/aiohttp_retry/tree/v1.2) and this gives `AttributeError`.

---

Old version could use

```
get(..., retry_attempts=3)
```

but new version needs

```
get(..., retry_options=ExponentialRetry(attempts=3)
```

or

```
RetryClient(..., retry_options=ExponentialRetry(attempts=3))
```

But `attempts` in `RetryClient` has default value `3` so you could skip it.

---

Other problem is that `RetryClient()` can't get `session` as parameter.
And it doesn't need it because it creates own `ClientSession()` in `__init__`

See [source code](https://github.com/inyutin/aiohttp_retry/blob/master/aiohttp_retry/client.py#L134)

---

This works for me:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp_retry import RetryClient, ExponentialRetry

class MyLogger():
    def debug(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('[debug]:', *args, **kwargs)
    
async def async_retry_fetch(url, retry_client):

    retry_options = ExponentialRetry(attempts=3)

    #async with retry_client.get(url) as response:
    # OR
    async with retry_client.get(url, retry_options=ExponentialRetry(attempts=3), raise_for_status=[500, 501]) as response:
        try:
            data = await response.json()
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception("Could not convert json")

    return data

async def main():
    urls = [
        "https://httpstat.us/200",
        "https://httpstat.us/500",
        "https://httpstat.us/501",
        "https://httpbin.org/status/500",
        "https://httpbin.org/status/501",
        "https://httpbin.org/json"
    ]

    #async with RetryClient(logger=MyLogger(), retry_options=ExponentialRetry(attempts=3), raise_for_status=[500, 501]) as retry_client:
    # OR
    async with RetryClient(logger=MyLogger()) as retry_client:
        api_calls = []
        
        for url in urls:
            api_calls.append(async_retry_fetch(url, retry_client))
            
        res = await asyncio.gather(*api_calls, return_exceptions=True)
 
        for item in res:
            print(item)
            print('---')

# --- start ---

asyncio.run(main())
```

Result:

```
[debug]: Attempt 0 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 0 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 0 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 0 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 0 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 0 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 1 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 1 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 1 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 1 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 2 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 2 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 2 out of 3
[debug]: Attempt 2 out of 3
Could not convert json
---
500, message='Internal Server Error', url=URL('https://httpstat.us/500')
---
501, message='Not Implemented', url=URL('https://httpstat.us/501')
---
500, message='INTERNAL SERVER ERROR', url=URL('https://httpbin.org/status/500')
---
501, message='NOT IMPLEMENTED', url=URL('https://httpbin.org/status/501')
---
{'slideshow': {'author': 'Yours Truly', 'date': 'date of publication', 'slides': [{'title': 'Wake up to WonderWidgets!', 'type': 'all'}, {'items': ['Why <em>WonderWidgets</em> are great', 'Who <em>buys</em> WonderWidgets'], 'title': 'Overview', 'type': 'all'}], 'title': 'Sample Slide Show'}}
```